# Run gradle task JavaExec in Android Gradle Plagin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I try to create gradle task with type JavaExec.
In gradle documentation I found than I need to aply java plugin. But this plugin is incompatible with android plugin. 
If I'm not apply java plugin I receive this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class package.TestM

Example my task:

```
task testA(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'package.TestM'
}
```

If I create java library module with same task I receive same error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Maybe I need set classpath variable? How can I get classpath in Java module in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task testA(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath += files(getBuildDir().toString() + "/intermediates/classes/debug")
    main = 'package.TestM'
}
```

maybe it is a good reason replace "debug" with a buildVariant variable.